# Are standings boosts shared to your fleet in missions?

Tags: eve-online

I'm currently grinding missions for faction standings on my main character, and I was wanting to help some of my new friends with isk/loot/salvage etc from the missions. When they're in the same fleet as me, do they get the same corp/faction standings increase from my doing my mission with them in my fleet as I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you share the mission rewards, up to 10 fleet members share the corp standing increase. The increase is split among the fleet, so if you would get +1% alone, then with 2 people you will each get +0.5%.

Faction standing increases are not shared.

Comment: This applies to ISK and LP mission payouts as well. Pirate Bounties are awarded to those on grid at the time of the kill.